# Matching Frontier - Unused Argument (outcome = "re78")

Tags: r, matching

I am following King et al's vignette on how to use the MatchingFrontier R program [pdf here](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/frontier/files/using_matchingfrontier.pdf),

But I am getting the following error:

> Error in makeFrontier(dataset = lalonde, treatment = "treat", outcome = "re78",  : unused argument (outcome = "re78")"

I have found others get the same error, but no solutions. Some suggest it has to do with the version - the GitHub call installs version 2.0.3. I'm not sure what to do. Any thoughts?

The code I am using is straight from the vignette linked above:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('ChristopherLucas/MatchingFrontier')

library(MatchingFrontier)
data('lalonde')

# Create a vector of column names to indicate which variables we
# want to match on. We will match on everything except the treatment
# and the outcome.
 match.on <- colnames(lalonde)[!(colnames(lalonde) %in% c('re78', 'treat'))]
 match.on # Print variables in match.on

 # Make the mahalanobis frontier
 my.frontier <- makeFrontier(dataset = lalonde,
                         treatment = 'treat',
                         outcome = 're78',
                         match.on = match.on)
```

Answer (score 2):

`outcome` is no longer one of the arguments to `makeFrontier()`, so it should be omitted from your function call. The package has changed since that vignette came out, so you should not rely on the vignette to be a guide.

The `?estimteEffects` help page provides an example of how to use `makeFrontier()` and estimate the treatment effects. The outcome variable is supplied to `estimateEffects()` instead of `makeFrontier()`.

---

Edit 2022/03/01:

`MatchingFrontier` has been updated once again, and the syntax has changed. Version 4.0.0 is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/IQSS/MatchingFrontier/), and documentation is available [here](https://iqss.github.io/MatchingFrontier/). Note this update fixes major bugs and introduces new functionality, but you should not expect results to replicate exactly from prior versions.